# Detect whether user denied process start in UAC

Tags: c#

When launching a new process in C# using

```
process.Start()
```

I can't seem to detect whether the user denied the process in the UAC window. In both cases the ExitCode is 0.

How can I know whether the user allowed or denied the process?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try something? How did you get the `ExitCode`. Actually, when you get a ExitCode equals `0` from a prompt command, means the commands works as expect (it comes from my experiencia with msbuild).

Comment: Can you use `CreateNoWindow = true` instead of `UseShellExecute = false`?

Comment: Tried the CreateNoWindow = true, but still gets the same result...

Comment: OK, now I'm feeling dumb... I was looking at the wrong process.Start()... (I have two, looked at the 1st instead of the 2nd...). Added the Win32Exception to it and everything works.